# Can't write unknown attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I execute model test, I get this:

```
  Failure/Error: sms_payment = create(:sms_payment)

     ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
       can't write unknown attribute `paid_parking_id`
```

I double checked: migration is done and I have in schema:

```
  create_table "sms_payments", force: :cascade do |t|
    #...
    t.integer  "paid_parking_id"
    end
```

My model:

```
belongs_to :paid_parking
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :sms_payment do
    #...
    paid_parking
  end
end
```

Comment: what is `paid_parking ` in your factory, how did you define it?

Comment: it is reference to paid parking model

Comment: Which rails version is it? Have you run your migrations on the test database as well? try `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate`, or `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: @JoeHalfFace I see, but how you define it?

Comment: @HieuPham - FactoryGirl uses method_missing to do it's magic. When a method is executed within factory block it will first try to identify it as a relationship and then will fall back to `<method_name>=` method. In case of relationship, it will find matching factory, create the model and assign it to the parent model. Since error message is about id assignment which happens after child model factory is run, this part of code works correctly.

Comment: @BroiSatse, hmm thanks for your explanation

Comment: thanks everyone for trying to help, issue was that I rolled back several migrations and made all operations through one, and this process made this error happen until I reset DB (drop - create - migrate). Lesson: if you rollback >1 migration you might want to reset DB